# Laravel 5.2 auth change 'users' table

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-artisan, laravel-5

I used the new feature in Laravel:

```
 php artisan make:auth
```

But when I register it will use the database table `users` by default, but I want to change that to an other table. And by default it uses `updated_at` and `created_at` in that table, I want to remove that too.

**Auth/AuthController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'voornaam' => $data['voornaam'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**app\User**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'voornaam', 'email', 'password',
];
```

This are the things I thought would change it, but they didn't. I hope somebody can tell me some more about this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change table name go to `app/User.php` and set property `$table` to custom one for example:

```
$table = 'new_table';
```

You should also change default migration. Go to: `/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` file and change `users` here for the same name. To remove timestamps you can remove line:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

however if I were you I would reconsider removing those timestamps

Comment: I hope you know this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673901/laravel-5-2-auth-change-id-to-customer-id

Answer (score 7):

**DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE VALIDATION IN REGISTERCONTOLLER.PHP AS WELL.**

from

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

to

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:company',
```

Answer (score 2):

By default model take its class name as table name !
I define a protected property at the top of `App/User.php`

```
protected $table = 'auth_users';
```

This tells laravel to use `auth_users` table instead of default `user` table.
and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Laravel 5.3 Change user table in Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514118/laravel-5-3-change-user-table-in-auth/) for an alternative solution, using modification in config/auth.php and RegisterController.php.

To disable the timestamps you may also use in the model class:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```