# Laravel 5.2 auth change 'id' to 'customer_id'

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In this topic I asked a question: [Laravel 5.2 auth change 'users' table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664087/laravel-5-2-auth-change-users-table/34664563#34664563)

But now my problem has changed. By default the users table has an `id`. But I want a `customer_id`, so I changed everything but it don't work. It keeps asking for an `id`.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `klanten` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

In the table `klanten` I have a `customer_id`, but it keeps asking for an `id`.

Things I've changed:

**config/auth**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'klanten',
    ],
```

**created a `klanten` migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('klanten', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('klant_id');
        $table->string('voornaam');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

If I remove timestamps it keeps asking for `created_at` and `updated_at` too.

**Controllers/Auth/AuthController**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'voornaam' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:klanten',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'voornaam' => $data['voornaam'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**app/User**

```
protected $table = 'klanten';

protected $fillable = [
    'voornaam', 'email', 'password',
];
```

I hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

edit your user model and add this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set the `$primaryKey` filed in the `User` model to specify the primary key of your table:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'customer_id';
```