# Laravel 5.3 Change user table in Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and used the `make:auth` artisan command to scaffold the login/registration system. I'm doing my login as companies, so I have a table called `Company`. How do I change the original sql to go get the email and password from the `Company` table instead of the `User` table?

I already tried to change in the `config/auth.php` file in the providers part, but when I changed `'model' => App\User::class,` to `'model' => App\Company::class,`, it started logging in, but regardless if the email and password input were completely wrong. Any ideas?

EDIT: After the `Company` registers and logs in, it has the ability to invite `Users`, therefore the original `User` table has to remain

Comment: Delete the default user table and create a custom one that won't be so hard.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin See my Edit please

Answer (score 8):

Laravel 5.3 has changes in the Auth implementation. For me, this way solved it:

First, provide a company table in the database that fulfils the criteria to be used for identification. Thus, it needs a name, email, password and remember_token column. Details can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#introduction-database-considerations).

In the config/auth.php change the users model to your company class.

```
    'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Company::class,
    ],
```

Create a Company class in the App folder that extends the Auth, so use:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
```

In the Company class, define fillable and hidden fields.

```
class Company extends Authenticatable {

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

In the RegisterController.php change "use App\User" to

```
use App\Company;
```

Adjust the **create** and **validator** function in the RegisterController.php with Company::create

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return Company::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:companies',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:**companies**'
 (table name for Company Model will be companies)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE VALIDATION IN REGISTERCONTOLLER.PHP AS WELL.**

from

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

to

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:company',
```