# Does Laravel5.3 support default authentication?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I have created a new laravel 5.3 project with cmd
"composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog"

And I expected laravel 5.3 support default authentication as laravel 5.0.
But I can't find views for authentication anywhere!

Do I have to make authentication from scratch?
Any answer will help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Laravel 5.3, If you have fresh installation, then by these commands you will get the Authentication ready.

> php artisan make:auth

once done then, add **DB** information in your `.env` file and then run this command

> php artisan migrate

this will make ready your `Authentication` ready. All this information is mentioned in Documentation, [Link is](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#introduction)

---

### **Edited**

if you only want to use `admins` table instead `users` table just follow these steps

in your `config/auth.php` rename the  `'table' => 'users',` index as `'table' => 'admins',` and also add/update this in line in `User.php` Model file

`protected $table ='admins';` after that run this command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: thanks and would you kindly explain How to use "admin" table as auth table? I created "admin" table having same structure as built in table "user". And made changes in config/auth.php but It doen't work. In addition i have to use "user" table for common users.Could you possibly teach me how to edit auth.php.

Comment: 1st tell me that whats the reason that you are creating separate table for `Admins` ? There is already lot of packages available who do `Role based access` famous one is `Entrust`.

Comment: It's because Administrators should login via admin table and manage common users registered in  user table.

Comment: Its better to use 3rd party Role base packages, these are Far better then your Manual creation and authentication

Comment: Right, but all i want is to use "admin" table for auth.Looking forward your help

Comment: You only want to use `admin` table instead `user` table ? for authentication ? or you want to use multiple Auth for admin as will as user?

Comment: right! I want to use admin table instead user table.I am so grateful for your kind help.

Comment: @MinhDan See my `Edited` section of the answer, I updated it.

Comment: Thanks but I am using Laravel5.3 and there is little difference in auth.php.
Could you possibly let me know the way on Laravel5.3?

Comment: See here, Some already asked the same question for changing the table,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514118/laravel-5-3-change-user-table-in-auth